# FETCH BULK COLLECT not return in package

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, cursor, fetch

Here's my problem, when I execute a package to archive some data it block on the command

```
FETCH cAPP_T_TMP BULK COLLECT
INTO t_app_t
limit nLIMIT;
```

But when the same command in a procedure inside of SQL Developper this operation take 16 secondes to run.

nLimit is iniatialyze at 50 000 in the package.

Just to mention, I have an other procedure in the package that work with the same strategy of archiving. The only difference is the cursor have a different select statement.

Here's the code that I have in the pacakge :

```
procedure APP_TRX (p_date in varchar2, p_tableName out varchar2, p_timeRequired out varchar2, p_nbLinesTransfered out varchar2) is

  cursor cAPP_T_TMP is
    SELECT
    APP.ID_APP,
    APP.ID_T,
    APP.ID_EVENT_CREA,
    APP.DT_CREA,
    APP.ID_EVENT_ANNUL,
    APP.DT_ANNUL,
    APP.ID_MAI,
    APP.ID_F,
    APP.M_APP,
    APP.C_APP,
    APP.T_C,
    max(ATB.DT_EPUR) AS DT_EPUR
    FROM APP_T APP
    JOIN ARCH_T_BODY ATB ON APP.ID_TRX = ATB.ID_TRX_TRANSACTION
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TP.ID_TRX FROM T_PAP TP WHERE TP.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TI.ID_TRX FROM T_INST TI WHERE TI.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TP.ID_TRX FROM T_P TP WHERE TP.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TCD.ID_TRX FROM T_CRE TCD WHERE TCD.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT MB.ID_TRX FROM M_BAN MB WHERE MB.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    GROUP BY APP.ID_APP,APP.ID_T,APP.ID_EVENT_CREA,APP.DT_CREA,APP.ID_EVENT_ANNUL,
    APP.DT_ANNUL,APP.ID_MAI,APP.ID_F,APP.M_APP,APP.C_APP,APP.T_C;

  type type_app_t is TABLE OF cAPP_T_TMP %ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  t_app_t type_app_t ;

  nLOT pls_integer := 1;
  nbDeleted int :=0;
  nbTransfered int :=0;
  nbTransferedTemp int :=0; nbAlreadyIn int :=0;

begin 
  trc.trc_on('ARCHIVE_APP_T');
  p_tableName := 'APP_T(B)';
  allBEGIN_TIMESTAMP := systimestamp;
  open cAPP_T_TMP ;  
  loop
    lotBEGIN_TIMESTAMP := systimestamp;
    dbms_application_info.set_module('before fetch',trim(to_char(nLOT * nLIMIT,'999G999G999')));

    FETCH cAPP_T_TMP BULK COLLECT  <-- here the command who block
    INTO t_app_t
      limit nLIMIT;

    dbms_application_info.set_module('AFTER FETCH',trim(to_char(nLOT * nLIMIT,'999G999G999')));
    exit when t_app_t.count = 0;
    ...
```

And this is the code that work in 16 secondes inside of Sql Developer:

```
declare
cursor cAPP_T_TMP is
    SELECT
    APP.ID_APP,
    APP.ID_T,
    APP.ID_EVENT_CREA,
    APP.DT_CREA,
    APP.ID_EVENT_ANNUL,
    APP.DT_ANNUL,
    APP.ID_MAI,
    APP.ID_F,
    APP.M_APP,
    APP.C_APP,
    APP.T_C,
    max(ATB.DT_EPUR) AS DT_EPUR
    FROM APP_T APP
    JOIN ARCH_T_BODY ATB ON APP.ID_TRX = ATB.ID_TRX_TRANSACTION
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TP.ID_TRX FROM T_PAP TP WHERE TP.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TI.ID_TRX FROM T_INST TI WHERE TI.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TP.ID_TRX FROM T_P TP WHERE TP.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TCD.ID_TRX FROM T_CRE TCD WHERE TCD.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT MB.ID_TRX FROM M_BAN MB WHERE MB.ID_TRX = APP.ID_TRX)
    GROUP BY APP.ID_APP,APP.ID_T,APP.ID_EVENT_CREA,APP.DT_CREA,APP.ID_EVENT_ANNUL,
    APP.DT_ANNUL,APP.ID_MAI,APP.ID_F,APP.M_APP,APP.C_APP,APP.T_C;

  type type_app_t is TABLE OF cAPP_T_TMP %ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  t_app_t type_app_t ;
  compt int := 0;
  nLIMIT pls_integer := 50000; 
begin 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('before open ' || systimestamp);
  open cAPP_T_TMP ;
  loop
    compt := compt +1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('before fetch ' || systimestamp);

    FETCH cAPP_T_TMP BULK COLLECT
    INTO t_app_t
      limit nLIMIT;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('after fetch ' || systimestamp);
    exit when t_app_t.count = 0;
    end loop;
  close cAPP_T_TMP ; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('after close ' || systimestamp || 'compt = ' || compt);

end;
```

As you can see its the same code but for a reason that I dont't know it just not work inside of the package.

I had validate with my other procedure inside of the package and the code is the same.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

I tried to extract the procedure into an anonym block and it works like a charm. So i did another test, I tried to call directly the procedure in my package but still get the problem. Finally I tried to copy the code that i have in my anonyme block directly inside the package but the same problem occur. Why in my package I can't archive the data when it goes really fast outside of the package.

Comment: Where is `cAPPLICATION_TRX_TMP` defined?  That doesn't seem to be the name of the cursor you've defined in either block.  When your session is blocked, what is it waiting on?  What are the wait events in `v$session` for example?

Comment: Add comment to cursor /* my_cursor */. Find sql_id from v$sql where sql_text like '%my_cursor%' and inspect xplan for it. (select * from table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(sql_id))).

Comment: @JustinCave the v$session do this output : before fetch 50,000

Comment: I assume that's the `module` from `v$session`?  What are the wait events?  What is `event` from `v$session`, for example?

Comment: @JustinCave event said : direct patch read

Comment: Where is `cAPPLICATION_TRX_TMP` defined? That doesn't seem to be the name of the cursor you've defined in either block.  Is the query plan the same in both cases?

Comment: Sorry it is cAPP_T_TMP I just forgot to change it when I post the question. But the problem still persist.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz it seems like that i cant find this output maybe its because it never succeed to complete a fetch even one time.

Comment: Yes im 100% sure that i execute my package because I can change the name in set_module and I see it when I run it. I run it on the same schema on the same database too.

Comment: Remove "index by pls_integer" from collection type definition and try again maybe something is wrong with populating associative array.

Comment: Well I tried to remove the instruction "index by pls_integer" but still have the error. I had just try to exec the procedure stand alone and its seems to work, I just dont know why, but when I'm in my package it didn't... I really have to make it work inside the package.

Comment: I watched the data that v%session_event gives me and it seems that is direct patch read who never end. all i can see is the time waited never syop getting higher...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the package was executed with another user who was optimized for OLTP by the DBA. And the process was trying to fetch on a table who have million of records. So when I executed it using my user it works way better.